# How to design voltage controller for non-linear circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, control, pid-controller, modeling, non-linear

Let's say I would like to design the PI controller for the \$v_C\$ voltage in the below given circuit.

[image]

I have attempted to design the PI controller in following steps.

1. **Development of the mathematical model for large signals**

In case the transistor is on following differential equation holds:

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\left(i_{in} - i_b - i_{out}\right) = \frac{1}{C}\left(i_{in} - \frac{v_C}{R_b} - i_{out}\right)
\$

In case the transistor is off following differential equation holds

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\left(i_{in} - i_{out}\right)
\$

We can combine both the above mentioned equations into one equation

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\left(i_{in} - \frac{v_C}{R_b}\cdot u - i_{out}\right)
\$

From the \$v_C\$ voltage control point of view the currents \$i_{in}\$ and \$i_{out}\$ are disturbances which should be compensated by the voltage controller so we can ommit them.

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\left(-\frac{v_C}{R_b}\cdot u\right)
\$

2. **Development of the averaged mathematical model**

In case we substitute average values of the capacitor voltage \$\left<v_C\right>_0\$ and switching function \$\alpha\$ into the differential equation we have averaged model in following form

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\left<v_C\right>_0}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C}\left(-\frac{\left<v_C\right>_0}{R_b}\cdot \alpha\right)
\$

3. **Development of the averaged mathematical model for small signals**

Due to the presence of the product of the average value of the capacitor voltage and duty cycle on the right hand side the differential equation for the average capacitor voltage is non-linear. It can be linearized about given steady state operating point in case following
formulas are substituted into the non-linear equation

\begin{eqnarray}
    \alpha &=& \alpha_e + \tilde{\alpha} \\
    \left<v_C\right>_0 &=& \left<v_C\right>_{0_e} + \widetilde{\left<v_C\right>_0}
\end{eqnarray}

i.e. we express average value of the capacitor voltage and switching function as a sum of the value corresponding to the steady state operating point and fluctuation about the steady state operating point. In case we ommit the product \$\widetilde{\left<v_C\right>_0}\cdot\widetilde{\alpha}\$ and exploit the fact that in the steady state operating point following holds \$\left<v_C\right>_{0_e}\cdot\alpha_e=0\$ (due to the fact that \$\frac{\mathrm{d}\left<v_C\right>_0}{\mathrm{d}t}=0\$), we have linearized model for small signals in following form

\$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\left<v_C\right>_0}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{R_b\cdot C}\left(\left<v_C\right>_{0_e}\cdot\widetilde{\alpha} + \widetilde{\left<v_C\right>_0}\cdot\alpha_e\right)
\$

For the linearized model we can write transfer function

\$
\frac{\widetilde{V}_C(s)}{\tilde{\alpha}(s)} = \frac{-\frac{\left<v_C\right>_{0_e}}{R_b\cdot C}}{s + \frac{\alpha_e}{R_b\cdot C}}
\$

By inspection of the transfer function two points are evident

- the system has negative dc gain which value depends on the operating point of the circuit
- the system pole depends on the operating point of the circuit

My questions are

1. As far as the negative dc gain I suppose that I can design the PI controller as if the
   dc gain was positive and then respect the negative sign with calculating the control
   error as \$e = y - r\$ instead of \$e = r - y\$ or with negative sign of the gains of
   the PI controller. Is that idea correct?
2. As far as the transfer function dependency on the operating point of the circuit. Do you
   think that I can design the PI controller for the "slowest" pole position i.e. for the
   situation \$\alpha_e = 0\$ and then verify the dynamic response for the "fastest" pole
   location i.e. for the situation \$\alpha_e = 1\$ and eventually reduce the proportional
   gain in case the response will be with high overshoot or oscillatory?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I thought I knew a fair bit about stuff but this question has got me foxed.

Comment: My goal is to design PI controller of the capacitor voltage. This voltage controller should ensure that the capacitor voltage doesn't exceed given limit.

Comment: But there is no power source in your circuit and, what does the diode bring to the party?

Comment: There are power sources at both sides of the circuit. I have ommited them because they are represented by the currents \$i_{in}\$ and \$i_{out}\$. As far as the diode. This diode acts as a freewheeling diode i.e. it creates path for the current in case the transistor is turning off.

Comment: Nope; I'm not getting it.

Comment: Why do you need a freewheeling diode for a resistor?

Comment: @Hearth because there is a parasitic inductance in the circuit.

Comment: Is there *that* much parasitic inductance? Are you switching the transistor off *that* fast? Are you using a transistor with *that* poor of an avalanche rating? I can't imagine the diode is necessary. Though it's not really hurting anything, I suppose.

Comment: Why do you need the I? Just put in a P using an opamp with a sufficient bandwidth. If you have inductances and you expect current changes so dramatic that you need a diode I don't think you should be worried about steady-state error (the tracking error (overshoot) will dominate) + the offset errors of the control circuit will be bigger than the steady-state error.